# Reverting many commits in IntelliJ by one commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'd like to revert many commits that were pushed overtime in IntelliJ, I was searching for relevant question but couldn't find any. Ideally I want the history to keep only one commit that would revert everything to the de0cbda [image]
Is there any easy way to do it in IntelliJ? Or perhaps through command line?

Comment: Is the history between `de0cbda` and `9d80426` linear? You could check it by `git log --oneline --graph de0cbda..9d80426`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as stated in your comment on my previous answer, you only want to revert changes done to one file in multiples commits just run :

```
git checkout de0cbda <PATH_TO_FILE>
```

---

> Bellow, my previous answer, before OP specified that he only want to revert changes for one file

Yep, `git revert` command with `-n` flag will revert changes and stage them without committing.

Thanks to @ElpieKay's comment, check if your history is linear, if yes, reset your current branch to #1d7e8e5 and then run the following command :

```
git revert HEAD~14 -n
```

`14` is the number of commits you want to revert.

If not, you can just list commits hashes in the `git revert` command :

```
git revert 1d7e8e5 0d2b8ea ... 39bdd21 de0cbda -n
```

At the end, review stashed changes and if you're happy with them just commit them with `git commit -m "Message"`

Comment: thanks for answering, thing is I want only one file to be reverted, and these commits also include changes to some other files

Comment: This point wasn't clear in your question. In this case, at the end, just before committing, run `git checkout -- <file>` for all files you don't want to revert.

Comment: that worked, however, the history and annotations remained the same, any way to clean it up?

Comment: Since you want to keep changes for your others file it's not recommended to rewrite history (this will be needed if you want to remove changes history for your file).

Comment: this exactly the point of reverting. I want to revert it to the state when I didn't change it, so next guy don't come to me when he sees the code

Comment: But it is reverted, you just kept the history because you have to keep changes done to other files. I think you should re-clarify your question if you want a more precise answer.