# Reverting multiple commits in IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, commit, revert

My question is the same as

[Reverting many commits in IntelliJ by one commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319677/reverting-many-commits-in-intellij-by-one-commit)

but *more specific*. In the linked question, it asks how to revert many commits at once in IntelliJ **or** by command line... since all feasible answers regard command line, I ask you how to revert more than one commit at once **using only IntelliJ**. I assume that the commits can be distributed in history and not consecutive.

I need to know how commit can be reverted **at once**, with only one operation.

Comment: To avoid getting Git command-line type answers, consider dropping the [tag:git] tag from your tag set here.

Comment: I won't. The question regards git also. It's up to the answerer to correctly read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select all commits in the history

[image]

then **revert commits** (not worked for my colleague, so I was misleaded!).

Answer (score 2):

The "[Undo changes in Git repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/undo-changes.html#revert-selected)" only mention locating the commit you want to revert in the Log tab of the Git tool window Alt+9, right-click it and select Revert Commit from the context menu.
(This option is also available from the context menu of a commit in the file History view)

Check if you can select multiple commits in that view.

[IDEA-174407](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-174407/Git-Revert-action-should-revert-commits-in-reverse-order) mentions

> When several commits selected, Git Revert action start reverting from the oldest commit but should start at the latest.

So that should be possible.